# C-sockets network is unreachable

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to implement a simple client/server program using sockets. My client is having trouble connecting to my server and i'm getting errno=101, Network is unreachable.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

if (argc == 1)
{
int sockfd, connfd;
struct sockaddr_in servaddress, cliaddress;
socklen_t servaddr_size;
int n;

printf("Welcome to Chat!\n");

//create socket
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // IPv4, TCP, IP

if (sockfd == -1) 
{
  printf("Socket creation failed...\n");
  exit(0);
}
else 
{
  memset(&servaddress, '\0', sizeof(servaddress));

  servaddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddress.sin_port = htonl(0);
  servaddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

  n = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddress, sizeof(servaddress));

  if (n < 0) 
  {
    printf("Socket bind failed...\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  
  socklen_t servsize = sizeof(servaddress);
  getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &servaddress, &servsize);

  printf("Waiting for a connection on %s ", inet_ntoa(servaddress.sin_addr));
  printf("port %d\n", ntohs(servaddress.sin_port));
  
  if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0) 
  {
    printf("Listen failed...\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Server listening..\n");
  }

  while(1) {
    servaddr_size = sizeof(cliaddress);
    connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddress, &servaddr_size);

    if(connfd < 0) 
    {
      printf("can't accept connection...\n");
      exit(0);
    }
    else 
    {
      printf("Found a friend! You receive first.\n");
      
      servcomm(connfd);
      
      close(sockfd);
    }
  }
}
}

else if(argc == 2) 
{
printf("Invalid number of arguments.\n");
exit(1);
}

else if(argc > 2) 
{
int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in servaddress;
char* portval;
char* ipval;

for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) 
{
  if(strcmp(argv[i], "-s") == 0) 
  {
    ipval = argv[i+1];
    while(*ipval) {
      if((isdigit(*ipval) == 0) && (*ipval != '.')) 
      {
        printf("IP is not valid.\n");
        exit(0);
      }
      ipval++;
    }
  }
  if(strcmp(argv[i], "-p") == 0) 
  {
    portval = argv[i+1];
    while(*portval) {
      if(isdigit(*portval++) == 0) 
      {
        printf("Port is not valid.\n");
        exit(0);
      }
    }
  }
}

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 

if (sockfd == -1) 
{
  printf("Socket creation failed...\n");
  exit(0);
}

memset(&servaddress, '\0', sizeof(servaddress));

servaddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddress.sin_port = htonl(atoi(portval)); 
servaddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipval);

// printf("portval %s\n", portval);
// printf("ipval %s\n", ipval);
// printf("atoi %d\n", atoi(portval));
// printf("port %d\n", servaddress.sin_port);
// printf("ip %d\n", servaddress.sin_addr.s_addr);

printf("Connecting to server...\n");
errno = 0;

if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddress, sizeof(servaddress)) != 0) {
  printf("connection to server failed...\n");
  printf("Error occurred while connecting, errno=%d, %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
  exit(0);
}
else
{
  printf("Connected!\n");
  printf("Connected to a friend! You send first.\n");
}

clicomm(sockfd);

close(sockfd);
}

return 0;
}
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaK5k.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5vdb.png)

I am sshed into the private network and the client and server are on the same local area network, so doesn't that mean that the 192.168.x.x ip address shouldn't be an issue?
Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: All code, input, and output should be posted directly in the question *as text*, not a picture of text and not a link to a picture of text.

Comment: Are the client and server on the same local network? 192.168.x.x addresses are private networks, you can't access them from the Internet.

Comment: If the server is behind a router, you need to configure port forwarding on the router, and the client should connect to the router's public address.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @Barmar The client and server are on the same local network and I am sshed into the private network so shouldn't I be able to access that ip address?

Comment: Won’t cause a network error, but you want htons() for ports (they are _s_horts, not _l_ongs)